# How do I grant the paketo builder access permissions to the docker socket when building from a docker image?

Tags: docker, buildpack, docker-daemon

When using buildpacks to build my spring boot application on Fedora I get the following error during the execution of the [spring-boot-plugin:build-image](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-build-image) goal:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: initializing analyzer: getting previous image: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

After digging into the goal and buildpacks, I found the following command in the [buildpack.io docs](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/) (by selecting "Linux" and "Container"):

```
docker run \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v $PWD:/workspace -w /workspace \
  buildpacksio/pack build <my-image> --builder <builder-image>
```

AFAICT this command should be equivalent to what happens inside of maven and it exhibits the same error.
My previous assumption was that the use in the `buildpacksio/pack` image doesn't have the access permissions to my docker socket. (The socket had 660 permissions and root:docker owner).

UPDATE: Even after updating to 666 permissions the issue still persists.

I don't really want to allow anyone to interact with the docker socket so setting it to 666 seems unwise. Is this the only option or can I also add the user in the container to the docker group?

Comment: You need to allow access in some way, more permissive permissions, add a user to the docker group or sudo your build command. Building with the Spring Boot build tools requires access to the daemon, as does pack, so you need to allow it or you won't be able to build. It should be no different than if you want to `docker build` a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the Fedora `docker` package is no longer the most up-to-date way to install Docker. See [the official Docker documentation](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/)
They both provide the same version number, but their build hash is different.

While I could not fully diagnose the difference between the two, I can report that it works with `docker-ce` and doesn't with `docker`.